# CEF with ChromiumFX "failed to establish GPU channel" error when run in VS debugger

Tags: c#, winforms, debugging, chromium, chromium-embedded

I am running a Winforms app using the standard ChromiumFX and ChromiumWebBrowser components. CEF version is 3.2171.2069_windows32, and ChromiumFX is 3.2171.1979.9, referenced as dlls.

I have only one form which has only the ChromiumWebBrowser control. The app is start-up code is the same as [here](https://bitbucket.org/chromiumfx/chromiumfx/src/16266bea96859a7047a8042f375205081bed3f57/CfxTestApp/Program.cs?at=default). When I download that source and run it, the test application runs ok in my VS debugger. This is using a more recent CEF and FX version.

In my app when I run it in the debugger it shows an empty form and the CEF log contains this entry:

> [0724/004741:ERROR:gpu_process_transport_factory.cc(437)] Failed to
>   establish GPU channel.

When I run the compiled exe outside of VS, it runs perfectly fine.
I can't figure out what the problem could be.
I tried running without the sandbox, I tried running in debug and in release.

So, to reproduce, download [ChromiumFX](https://bitbucket.org/chromiumfx/chromiumfx/downloads/ChromiumFX-3.2171.1979.9.7z) and CEF version 3.2171.2069 (from [here](https://cefbuilds.com/). Create a WinForms project, reference ChromiumFX and ChromiumWebBrowser. Add one form containing a WebBrowser, update the Program.cs to match the one shown earlier. And copy CEF files to the paths defined in Program.cs.

Comment: This is rather strange. I run the test app through the debugger all the time and never got any problems with that. That version you are using is quite outdated, is there any reason you can't use a current version?

Comment: I just updated the 2171 branch. Can you try the new binaries?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some off-list discussion with the OP the problem was found:

You have to disable the "Enable the Visual Studio hosting process" checkbox in Project Properties->Debug. It interferes with the secondary processes.

Alternatively, use `CfxSettings.BrowserSubprocessPath` and specify the path to your executable.